# A MySql function is not compiling and I cant find a reason

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-error-1064

Hi I am generally an oracle guy trying to try my hands in MySql. I have understood the basic concepts and now trying to develop functions. while doing so facing a problem as below.
I apologise if this be the silliest question in entire Stackoverflow, but I am at my wits end
My code :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION test1 returns int (11)
begin
DECLARE id int(11) default 3;
return id;
end;
$$
delimiter ;
```

I am getting the below error while trying to create the above function

12:35:59    CREATE FUNCTION test1 returns int (11) begin DECLARE myid int(11) default 3; return myid; end;  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(11) begin DECLARE myid int(11) default 3; return myid; end' at line 1 0.000 sec

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing () after the name of your function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION test1() RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
  DECLARE id int(11) DEFAULT 3;
  RETURN id;
END;
$$
delimiter ;
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88ff2/2).